# How to process conflict on updating listitem by a thread and main thread

Tags: android, listview

I have a download list, it will be updated by a download thread call back, and in some cases, the list will be updated by NotifyDatasetChanged(), so the conflict will be happened, since they both need to call getview() method.

Download thread ---> call back ---> getview() for specify item view ---> update viewholder

Main Thread ---> refresh data ---> NotifyDatasetChanged() ---> call getview() ---> update viewholder

How to deal with these situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you don't want to be manipulating your data from 2 different threads.  At least, not without protection.  Plus you cannot modify views on a non-UI thread.  Update the backing data for the view (not the view itself, just the item which the view represents) and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.  The list will work with the adapter at that point to re-render the view and at that point your adapter can update the view accordingly.

Comment: Thanks guys.Do you mean update data source instead of view itself? But, I am not sure if it has problem for invoke NotifyDatasetChange() for every 500ms?

Comment: Yes, just update backing data rather than the view itself.  Even then, you'll want to make sure you protect the access to your data.  Updating data every 500ms would be very aggressive.

Comment: Thanks Larry. I think I need to change the original design.

Comment: Not a problem, hope it was helpful.

Comment: @Simon You can also check DiffUtil. It can be very helpful if you update your list very frequently.